# Error en fecha al crear csv [Object Object]

Tags: nodejs, csv, google-cloud-functions

Tengo una función que crea un csv a partir de un query y posteriormente lo sube a un bucket de cloud storage

```
// Define el SQL query que deseas ejecutar en BigQuery.
const sqlQuery = `SELECT ClienteUnico,EmailContratante,Telefono,Fecha_emision,fecha_evento,Tipo,Poliza
FROM \`inter-cdp-prod-1.productos_digitales.signup_successful\`
where Grupo = 'DIGITAL' and tipo in ( 'CocheSeguro','MedicoSeguro')`;

// Ejecuta el query en BigQuery.
bigquery
 .query({
  query: sqlQuery,
  // Opcional: Configura otros parámetros de consulta si es necesario.
  location: 'US', // Ubicación de BigQuery, si es diferente de la configuración predeterminada.
 })
 .then(([rows]) => {
  if (rows.length === 0) {
   console.log('No se encontraron resultados.');
   return;
 }

// Convierte los resultados a un archivo CSV.
const csvData = [];
 csvData.push(['ClienteUnico', 'EmailContratante', 'Telefono', 'Fecha_emision', 'fecha_evento', 'Tipo', 'Poliza']); // Agrega los encabezados del CSV

rows.forEach((row) => {
  if(Object.values(row)=== null){
    return []
  }else{
  csvData.push([row.ClienteUnico, row.EmailContratante, row.Telefono, row.Fecha_emision, row.fecha_evento, row.Tipo, row.Poliza]);
  }
});

// Define el nombre del archivo CSV que se creará en Cloud Storage.
const fileName = 'exitosos.csv';
const csvString = csvData.map((row) => row.join(',')).join('\n');

// Sube el archivo CSV al bucket de Cloud Storage.
const file = storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName);
const stream = file.createWriteStream({
  metadata: {
    contentType: 'text/csv',
  },
});

stream.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});

stream.on('finish', () => {
  console.log(`Archivo CSV '${fileName}' subido a Cloud Storage.`);
});

// Escribe el contenido del CSV en el archivo.
stream.end(csvString);
```

Mi problema es que el csv que se crea tiene la fecha como  **[Object Object]**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al imprimir el csvData veo que la fecha aparece de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Imprímelo en consola y revisa que viene.

Comment: imprimi el csvData y viene de la sigueinte forma "BigQueryDate { value: '2023-07-17' }," en el csv final viene tal cual se ve, con el error en la fecha  por ejemplo "85469, [object Object], 1"

Answer (score 0):

El problema solo era que el campo de fecha venia con un arreglo dentro en el que  "valor" tenia el dato de la fecha.

Se resolvio al acceder a ese valor en el push

`row.fecha_evento.value`

Comment: Tienes  razón, mala mía.